# How can I prevent a UIButton from highlighting when pressed?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton

When an `UIButton` is pressed, the normal situation is that it will be highlighted i.e. a shadow like layer will cover the image. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? Is there an attribute to handle this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You normally don't press a button with Xcode, you use your finger (or mouse). But nitpicking aside: `adjustsImageWhenHighlighted` set to `NO` will do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

If you make a custom subclass of the UIButton you can override setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted to do nothing

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted
{ 
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also achieve this through Interface Builder.  Uncheck "Highlighted Adjusts Image" in the Attributes inspector.

[image]