# How to prevent a UIButton from changing when touched?

Tags: uibutton, ios5, xcode4.2

I have a button that pretty much takes an entire xib so that I can push another viewController on the screen if any part of the original view is touched.  I've created an IBOutlet to this button and it works great, however I don't want the entire window to turn "blue" when it is touched (similar to when a small button is pressed).  I've tried the following two methods that I found in a similar SO post: [How can I prevent a UIButton from highlighting when pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333027/how-can-i-prevent-a-uibutton-from-highlighting-when-pressed), but neither method works.  Is there something else I need to set up?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.entireWindowButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;

    [self.entireWindowButton setImage: [self.entireWindowButton imageForState:UIControlStateNormal] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is old question but if you set the UIButtons type to custom then "adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO" will work and it is set to NO by default.